# Division of two functions in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm very new to Haskell and I'm trying to make a basic function which finds the mean of a list. I've almost got it solved, except for the last bit of division I have to do.

```
randInts = take 5 $ randoms (mkStdGen 11) :: [Int]

listSum :: (Num a) => [a] -> a
listSum [] = 0
listSum (x:xs) = x + listSum xs

listLength :: (Num a) => [a] -> a
listLength [] = 0
listLength (x:xs) = 1 + listLength xs

listMean :: (Num a) => [a] -> a
listMean [] = 0
listMean x = (listSum x) / (listLength x)
```

This is what I started with, where listSum and listLength basically have the same functionality as the sum and length operators on lists respectively and listMean takes those two and divides them. When I run this, however, I get an error saying *"Could not deduce (Fractional a) arising from a use of ‘/’ from the context: Num a"*

At first, I just thought I had used the wrong type and switched listMean to start with listMean :: (Fractional a) => [a] -> a. This allowed me to compile, but when I attempted to run it by giving it randInts, but instead I got the error message "No instance for (Fractional Int) arising from a use of ‘listMean’."

I am not sure what I am missing here. Could I have some advice please?

Comment: You mean removing fractional? I did that and it gave me an error saying "Expected a type, but ‘a’ has kind ‘Constraint’"

Comment: That gives me the error "No instance for (Fractional Int) arising from a use of ‘listMean’"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a guess: you are testing this in ghci with `listMean randInts`. This is a problem, because `Int` doesn't support division via `(/)` but rather supports integer division via `div` (to avoid a certain class of bugs that crops up in languages that conflate the two).

You have a two obvious choices, namely, convert your `Int`s to something that does support division (e.g. `Double`) or generate random `Double`s in the first place.

```
listMean (map fromIntegral is) :: Double
listMean . take 5 . randoms $ mkStdGen 11 :: Double
```

By the way, if my guess is correct: in the future, you should really include *all* the details of the things you did, in so much detail that we playing along at home could follow them and see the exact same error; *and* you should include the entire content of the error, especially since in this case it mentions the code snippet that caused it and would have made diagnosis instantaneous.

Comment: I had not thought to test this with a float before and I see it works with float values now. Thanks for the advice (although hilariously now I'm having trouble getting the interpreter to convert an int to a float)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that:

```
(Num a) => [a] -> a
```

Applied with `[Int]`, both `listSum` and `listLength` returns `Int`, which does not support `/`. You need to convert the return values before division:

```
listMean :: (Num a, Integral a) => [a] -> Double
listMean [] = 0
listMean x = (fromIntegral $ listSum x) / (fromIntegral $ listLength x)
```